# Accessing all data using Laravel Eloquent relationship(one to many/Inverse)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models namely doctors model and doctors_room model. I used eloquent one to many relationship to cater to doctors having multiple rooms. Here's my code for my doctor's model

```
class Doctors extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'doctor_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'specialization_id_fk',
    ];

    public function specializations() 
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Specializations', 'specialization_id_fk');

    }

    public function doctorRooms()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\DoctorRooms', 'doctor_id_fk', 'doctor_id');

    }

}
```

and here's for my doctorRooms model

```
class DoctorRooms extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'doctor_room_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'room',
        'doctor_id_fk',
    ];


    public function doctorsInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Doctors', 'doctor_id_fk', 'doctor_id');
    }
}
```

When I tried to access a data in my doctorRooms model I keep on getting "Property [room] does not exist on this collection instance". Here's my code for my doctors controller

```
class DoctorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $doctors = Doctors::all();
        $rooms = DoctorRooms::all();

        foreach($doctors as $doctor) {
            echo $doctor->doctorRooms->room;
        }
    }

}
```

Heres the result of $doctors when I echo it formatted as JSON.

```
[ 
    { 
        "doctor_id":1,
        "first_name":"Aracely",
        "last_name":"Ullrich",
        "specialization_id_fk":12,
        "doctor_rooms":[ 
            { 
                "doctor_room_id":1,
                "room":"151",
                "doctor_id_fk":1
            },
            { 
                "doctor_room_id":3,
                "room":"152",
                "doctor_id_fk":1
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "doctor_id":2,
        "first_name":"Marjolaine",
        "last_name":"Sipes",
        "specialization_id_fk":21,
        "doctor_rooms":[ 
            { 
                "doctor_room_id":2,
                "room":"131",
                "doctor_id_fk":2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can do this using laravel query builder but for the sake of MVC ill stick to laravel eloquent ORM.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use with() $doctors = Doctors::with('doctorRooms')->get();

Comment: I already tried that but still im getting Property [room] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `room` attribute of a single model not an attribute on the Collection containing many of those models.

```php
foreach ($doctors as $doctor) {
    foreach ($doctor->doctorRooms as $room) {
        echo $room->room;
    }
}
```

`$doctors` is a Collection and each Doctor has a Collection of DoctorRooms to iterate over.

Don't forget to eager load the relationship to remove the extra queries from the iterations.